# Why is the Paypal transaction details array being returned empty?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have created a buyer and seller test account on Paypal sandbox. I've also created a Paypal button.

The Paypal button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6M75NVDV8ZHR8">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I've enabled the IPN and set the notification URL there.
While creating the Paypal button I insert my site URL for the successful transaction.
*A successful transaction and IPN notification share the same URL.*

Here's the PHP script for the referred URL:

```
<?php  
  // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'  
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';  
  print_r($_POST);

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  
    echo "loop";
    echo $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  
    echo $req .= "&$key=$value";  
  }

  // post back to PayPal system to validate  
  $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";  
  $header.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";  
  $header.= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";  
  
  $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
  
  if (!$fp) {  
    // HTTP ERROR  
  } else {  
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);  

    while (!feof($fp)) {  
      $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);  
      if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  
        echo " PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED! "; 
      }
      else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        echo " PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!  ";
      }  
    }  
    fclose ($fp);  
  }
?>
```

The `print_r` function only prints `Array()` and in the foreach loop nothing is displayed.

Only the `PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALLY!` gets displayed on the page.

What is the problem here?
Because I want to insert some data on a successful transaction.

---

### UPDATED

Here is my post array:

```
Array
(
)
DoDirectPayment failed: Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d05%2d03T12%3a54%3a08Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 51176eef6a5
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51%2e0
    [BUILD] => 2860716
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10527
    [L_ERRORCODE1] => 10563
    [L_ERRORCODE2] => 10562
    [L_ERRORCODE3] => 81234
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid%20Data
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE1] => Invalid%20Data
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE2] => Invalid%20Data
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE3] => Invalid%20Parameter
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%2e%20Please%20enter%20a%20valid%20credit%20card%20number%20and%20type%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE1] => This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%2e%20Please%20enter%20a%20valid%20credit%20card%20expiration%20month%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE2] => This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%2e%20Please%20enter%20a%20valid%20credit%20card%20expiration%20year%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE3] => ExpDate%20%3a%20Invalid%20Parameter
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE1] => Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE2] => Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE3] => Error
)
```

I changed the ipn.php code and now I am getting this error: "Invalid credit card number".

I have created the buyer account using pre-configured and it generates the credit card number randomly.

Now when I went to add/edit credit card, There I can't edit the card number only the address and expiry date.

And also can't add a new credit card instead an error of this credit card is assigned to another Paypal account message.

Comment: Did you checked it in localhost?

Comment: no, I checked it on live url.

Comment: set the notify url in the hidden variable also. Then write the paypal response to a .txt file to verify it.

Comment: I changed the ipn.php code and now I am getting this error `Invalid credit card number`. I have created the buyer account using preconfigured and it generates the credit card number randomly. Now when I went to add/edit credit card, There I can't edit the card number only the address and expiry date. And also cant add a new credit card instead an error of `This credit card is assigned to another paypal account` message.

Answer (score 0):

The print_r echoes its output to paypal's script. You probably want it logged to file, so that you could view it later

Comment: how will i do this? and why it is returning the invalid payment?

Comment: file_put_contents("log.txt", print_r($_POST,true));

Comment: while tried your code when I open the log.txt file it only have `Array()`.